# Monaco-Editor: How can I prevent webpack from generating unnecessary files?

Tags: webpack, configuration, monaco-editor

I am new for the Monaco Editor and tried to use it as the official example:

https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/tree/main/samples/browser-esm-webpack-typescript

It was successful but I found that the Webpack generated some files which seems to be useless.

[image]

Assume that I am interesting in the only frontend languages such that `Typescript`, `Javascript` and `JSON`, I think the Webpack does not need to generate files which related to other languages such that `cpp`, `csharp`, etc.

I tried to use the `monaco-editor-webpack-plugin` with options specifying only necessary languages but the `node_module_monaco-editor_esm_vs_basic-languages_....js` files are still generated. (And they are many!)

Please let me know how to remove the useless files.
Thank you.